# Put Visual Studio Code breakpoint on Javascript inside HTML file

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-debugger

i konw it's not a best practice to put obtrusive JavaScript inside HTML code.

I installed the extension "Debugger for Chrome" and i noticed that is not possible to put breakpoint and debug Javascript Code inside HTML files. Is it correct? Or i am missing some configurations?

```
<body>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c=1; //<---Unable to put breakpoint here
        alert('Hello');//<---or here
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to follow this set of instructions to setup Visual Studio Code debugging for your project. Instructions are found on the link below

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Then you can launch your app by either pressing the `F5` key or clicking the run button from the Visual Studio Code

Comment: O! I just checked again, my bad. OP's code was right

Comment: Hello jay, thank you for the answer. I have already set up the environment. Debugging inside 'somehting.js' files included throught <script src="something.js"> is OK. I can't put breakpoint and debug code that is in the middle of the HTML like i showed you. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello! Gianluigi,
How do you launch the solution?